# Getting all Instances of SQL Server on a given Remote Server with Powershell while tackling SqlConnectionStringBuilder.Encrypt Property

Tags: sql-server, powershell, encryption, ssl-certificate, sqlclient

I have the following once perfectly running code, which stopped working due to a recent breaking change that uses encrypted by default.

```
Import-Module -Name SqlServer
Import-Module -Name ImportExcel

# Definieren der Liste von Servernamen
$servers = @("DE-SQL-03")



# Definieren der Anmeldeinformationen des Domänenadministrators
$Username = "DOMAIN\badmin" 

$Password = Read-Host "Enter the password for $Username" -AsSecureString
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username, $Password)
#tagesdatum
$currentDate = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-MM")
# Excel-Ausgabedatei definieren
$OutputFile = "C:\scripts\DatabaseAndLogSizes_$($servers)_$($currentDate).xlsx"



# Für jede Server-Instanz die Datenbankgrößen und Füllstände abrufen und ausgeben
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    Write-Host "Server: $($server)"
  
    
    # Remotesitzung auf dem Server öffnen
    $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -ConfigurationName "PowerShell.7" -Credential $Credential 
    
    
    # Abrufen aller SQL Server-Instanzen auf dem Server
  **  $instances = Invoke-Command -Session $Session  -ScriptBlock {
        Import-Module -Name SqlServer
        Get-ChildItem -Path "SQLSERVER:\SQL\$($using:server)" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name   ### Parameter mitnehmen?**
    }

    # Für jede Instanz die Datenbankgrößen und Füllstände abrufen und ausgeben
    foreach ($instance in $instances) {
        Write-Host "Instance: $($instance)"
```

Get-Childitem now gives following error, note that it breaks EXACTLY HERE "Get-ChildItem -Path "SQLSERVER:\SQL$($using:server)" where I do not use Invoke-sqlcmd.
Error:
"Invoke-Sqlcmd: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)"

I have been banging my head on the wall how to fix this? Where would I put my `Encrypt=optional` and/or my  `TrustServerCertificate=true`? SMO Objects?   `$serverConnection = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection -ArgumentList $server` ?? Brings new Problems and the old one too.
Creating a credential object doesn't seem to work.

How to query a server for all it's SQL Server Instances using Powershell while exceuting my code on my local machine?

using

```
$serverConnection = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection -ArgumentList $server
    $serverConnection.LoginSecure = $true

    # Füge TrustServerCertificate=True zum Verbindungs-String hinzu
    $serverConnection.ConnectionString = $serverConnection.ConnectionString + ";TrustServerCertificate=True"

    # Verbindung herstellen
    $serverConnection.Connect()
```

tried:

```
$instances = Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
    param($server)
    Import-Module -Name SqlServer

    
    $connectionString = "Server=$($server);Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True"
    $connection = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection -ArgumentList $connectionString
    $connection.Open()

    # Verwenden Sie die benutzerdefinierte Verbindung, um die SQL Server-Instanzen abzurufen
    Get-ChildItem -Path "SQLSERVER:\SQL\$($server)" -Connection $connection | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
    $connection.Close()
} -ArgumentList $server
```

tried

```
invoke-sqlcmd
$size = Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
    param($instance, $query)
    Import-Module -Name SqlServer
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $instance -Query $query -ConnectionString "Server=$instance;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True"
} -ArgumentList $instance, $querySize
```

---

invoke-sqlcmd as suggested:
edited out for logical error.... need more time to try this

Comment: For `Invoke-Sqlcmd` `TrustServerCertificate` is a switch: `Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $instance -Query "SELECT @@VERSION;" -TrustServerCertificate` for example

Comment: @ThomA the whole SqlServer v22.0.59 PowerShell module switched its backend to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, which is the source of this problem, so it affects pretty much all of the module's functions that require a connection.

Comment: Since the problem is new to SqlServer v22.0.59 (which includes a new `-TrustServerCertificate` switch for `Invoke-Sqlcmd`, btw)... have you considered just downgrading to the previously working v21?

Comment: I can't actually replicate this problem with `Get-ChildItem` with SqlServer 22.0.59.

Comment: Invoke-Sqlcmd is a path I am trying. To me this SHOULD work but NO  luck yet! It should be something around the lines :
$session= New-PSSessionObject
Invoke-command....
Invoke-sqlcmd.... I will provide detailed error of this asap.
-----
@ThomA the whole SqlServer v22.0.59 PowerShell module switched its backend to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, which is the source of this problem,--- YES YES! I upgraded because I had a bug in my "old" version which was fixed in 22.0.59. Talk about a fix that is worse then the bug. I will hunt for a version that works. ---

Comment: To replicate: Target Server is in same domain and has an outdated 2019 Version and a brand new 2022 installed.Funny thing: my code WORKED before I "fixed" the bug...

Comment: Downgrading is not an option either. It changes the Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlContext Data Connection in the background. So once you installed the "new" SQLServer Module 22.0.59 you ares stuck with it. Script works flawlessly on old Server with old SQLServer Module  21.1.18245. Still no solution!

Error:
WARNING: Could not obtain SQL Server Service information. An attempt to connect to 'de-sql-03' failed with the following error: Could not load type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlContext' from assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Comment: Unless you've deliberately uninstalled the previous version(s) you should still have them available for import. What's the output of either `Get-InstalledModule -AllVersions -Name SqlServer | Format-Table Name,Version` or `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name SqlServer | Format-Table Name,Version`? What happens if your script uses `Import-Module -Name SqlServer -MaximumVersion 21.1.18256` or similar?

Comment: Get-InstalledModule -AllVersions -Name SqlServer | Format-Table Name,Version

Name      Version
----      -------
SqlServer 21.1.18245
SqlServer 22.0.59
I will try your Import-Module -Name SqlServer -MaximumVersion 21.1.18256 asap!

Comment: Import-Module -Name SqlServer -MaximumVersion 21.1.18245 (sic!) is not working sadly. 

Errors:

_Update-TypeData: Error in TypeData "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server": The member UpdateLevel is already present.
...10 more
Import-Module: Assembly with same name is already loaded._
aaaand finaly: 
_provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted_

This is tough. Any more ideas?

Comment: If I completly remove the new module it seems SQLServer Module is then missing something:
`uninstall-Module -Name SQLServer -requiredVersion 22.0.59 -Force`

`WARNING: Could not obtain SQL Server Service information. An attempt to connect to 'de-sql-03' failed with the following error: Could not load type 
'Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlContext' from assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.`